# Shell alias expansion under ESXi host does not auto complete - AND - detecting if running interactively

Tags: sh, esxi

Since ESXi does not come with bash, I am sourcing an .sh file to set up some custom aliases for common commands while connected via ssh.

On other distros like RHEL, I can type part of an alias and hit tab to autocomplete. This does not seem to work under ESXi 7.x.

Is there a switch or something that I can turn on to make autocomplete work for custom aliases, or is this just a limitation of the shell that ESX offers?
NOTE: If type `l<tab>` then I DO get the built in commands that start with L.

Also while I'm on the topic of the ESXi shell… On RHEL I have this line in my .bashrc file

```
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return
```

Purpose of this code being that if the current session is not being ran interactively then return else run rest of code.

When I run this on esx I get the error `sh: *i*: unknown operand`.  Does the shell not support this substring methodology?

If I run `echo $-`  then I get “**smi**” as the output.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably know ESXi provides ash (NOT bash) and Busybox.  Although Busybox includes ash as I recall ESXi uses a custom built executable (check where /bin/ash points or doesn't point to).  The Wikipedia article on ash gives a good overview of ash and its minimalist philosopy.  Shell history was originally not included and autocompletion is definitely regarded as a nice to have that didn't make the cut.  Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: Followup question  - Should I be using #!/bin/sh  or #!/bin/ash at the top of my scripts and why one vs the other?

Comment: Just as on Linux and BSD /bin/sh is advised unless your script requires the additional functionality.